# How to store the identifications for goroutines so that I can stop them later

Tags: go

I am trying to create multiple goroutines and keep them running concurrently. Then when a request comes in I want to identify one of them them and stop only that particular goroutine while the rest contiue

## File 1

```
mm := remote_method.NewPlayerCreator()

mm.NewPlayer("Leo", "Messi")

// Lets just assume that the method call starts a bot which starts playing football

mm.NewPlayer("Cristiano", "Ronaldo")

mm.StopPlayer("Leo", "Messi")
```

## File 2

```
package remote_method

type PlayerCreator struct {
        playerNameChannelNumberMap (map[Player](chan int))
}

type Player struct {
        firstName, lastName string
}

func NewPlayerCreator() DeclaredType {
        var nameChannelMap (map[Player](chan int))
        m := PlayerCreator{nameChannelMap}
        return m
}

func (mm NewPlayerCreator) NewPlayer(firstName string, lastName string) {
     // Update the playerNameChannelNumberMap to add this new Player in the map
     // Since maps are basically called by reference, the map withe the file 1 should be updated or should it ?
     // Call to a goroutine that would create a new player and the player keeps on running in an infinite loop
     // I can add the goroutine code in this method and not create a new method for the goroutine, if it makes more sense like this
}

func (mm NewPlayerCreator) StopPlayer(firstName string, lastName string) {
     // Find the player channel in the map and send a done signal on receiving which it exits
     // Remove the player entry from the map
}
```

What are the best known practices for doing such a thing ?
TIA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is "you can't". Goroutines are not like Unix processes or threads; there's no PID or thread ID.

You terminate a goroutine by writing a message to a channel shared between the main routine and the goroutine telling it you want it to go away instead of forcibly terminating it yourself.

I won't reproduce the entire article from https://blog.golang.org/pipelines; 
you would be better off reading it there. High points:

- You make it possible to cancel a goroutine by sharing a channel with it (most often named `done`). The actual type of what you send on this channel is unimportant.
- When you want to send a "everyone shut down" message, you close the `done` channel. This causes any read on the channel to immediately succeed with a zero-valued instance of the channel's type, effectively broadcasting a "stop" to every goroutine reading the channel.
- The goroutines have at their core a select loop, which checks for input available on any input channel and on the `done` channel. Once the channel is closed, the `done` channel has input ready, and the goroutine cleans up and exits.

The `context` type wraps this up and a number of other niceties; reading the https://blog.golang.org/context article will give you more details on using contexts to control goroutines.

---